nextjs application goes unresponsive
I am building a nextjs application where i have multiple tabs , table to display data etc. whenever the table code is uncommented the freezing of the code occurs which stops only when i close the tab. tested on browsers: chrome and edge.
i have a very identical code which works absolutely correct.
here is the code
"use client";

import React, { useState, useMemo, Suspense, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "~/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "~/components/ui/input";
import { Tabs, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from "~/components/ui/tabs";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "~/components/ui/table";
import {
  ColumnFiltersState,
  SortingState,
  VisibilityState,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  getFilteredRowModel,
  getPaginationRowModel,
  getSortedRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";
import {
  Eye,
  Download,
  Pencil,
  Trash2,
  Plus,
  Search,
  ArrowUpDown,
  Import,
} from "lucide-react";
import { Module } from "./types";
import { columns } from "./columns";
import UpdateModuleCard from "./update-module-card";
import QuestionDrawer from "./questionDrawer";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { api } from "~/trpc/react";
import CreateModuleCard from "~/components/content/modules/module/questions/CreateModule";

export default function ModulesPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: {
    moduleId: string;
    levelId: string;
    courseId: string;
    country: string;
  };
}) {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>([]);
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [showUpdateModule, setShowUpdateModule] = useState(false);
  const [selectedModule, setSelectedModule] = useState<Module | null>(null);
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("questions");
  const [createModule, setCreateModule] = useState(false);
  const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(false);
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("swedish");

  const {
    data: questions,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = api.content.fetchLevel.useQuery({
    id: params.levelId,
    language: language,
    type: "questions",
  });
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(params, "params");
    console.log(language, "language");
  }, []);

  
  const table = useReactTable({
    data: questions?.questions || [],
    columns,
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: {
      sorting,
      columnFilters,
      columnVisibility,
      rowSelection,
    },
  });

  const handleTabChange = useCallback((tab: string) => {
    setSelectedTab(tab);
    if (tab === "questions") {
        router.push(
            `/content/country/${params.country}/courses/${params.courseId}/modules/module/${params.moduleId}/level/${params.levelId}/questions`,
        );
    } else if (tab === "theory") {
        router.push(
            `/content/country/${params.country}/courses/${params.courseId}/modules/module/${params.moduleId}/level/${params.levelId}/theory`,
        );
    }
}, [params, router]);


const handleLanguageChange = (value: string) => {
  setLanguage(value as 'swedish' | 'english')
  console.log(value, "value");
};

const handleSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
  const value = event.target.value
  setSearchQuery(value)
  table.getColumn('name')?.setFilterValue(value)
}

const handleEdit = () => {
  const selectedRows = table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows
  if (selectedRows.length === 1) {
    setSelectedModule(selectedRows[0].original)
    setShowUpdateModule(true)
  }
}

const handleUpdateModule = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  // Handle module update logic here
  setShowUpdateModule(false)
}

const handleRowClick = (row: Module) => {
  setSelectedModule(row)
  setIsDrawerOpen(true)
}


  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (isError) {
    return <div>Error</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {showUpdateModule && selectedModule ? (
        <UpdateModuleCard
          module={selectedModule}
          onClose={() => setShowUpdateModule(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <div className="flex p-8">
          <div
            className={`flex-grow transition-all duration-300 ${isDrawerOpen ? "pr-96" : ""}`}
          >
            <div className="mb-6 flex items-center justify-between">
              <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">
                {selectedTab === "questions" ? "Questions" : "Theory"}
              </h1>

              <div className="flex space-x-2">
                <Button onClick={()=>{setCreateModule(true); }}>
                  <Plus className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Create{" "} Question
                  {/* {selectedTab === "questions" ? "Question" : "Theory"} */}
                </Button>

                <Button variant="outline">
                  <Import className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                  Bulk Import
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <Tabs
              value={selectedTab}
              onValueChange={handleTabChange}
              className="mb-6"
            >
              <TabsList>
                <TabsTrigger value="theory">Theory</TabsTrigger>
                <TabsTrigger value="questions">Questions</TabsTrigger>
              </TabsList>
            </Tabs>
            <div className="mb-4 flex items-center justify-between">
              <div className="relative flex items-center">
                <Search className="absolute left-2 top-2.5 h-4 w-4 text-gray-500" />
                <Input
                  placeholder="Search..."
                  value={searchQuery}
                  // onChange={handleSearch}
                  className="pl-8 pr-8"
                />
                <Button variant="outline" size="icon" className="ml-2">
                  <ArrowUpDown className="h-4 w-4" />
                </Button>
              </div>
              <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <Button variant="outline" size="icon">
                  <Eye className="h-4 w-4" />
                </Button>
                <Button variant="outline" size="icon">
                  <Download className="h-4 w-4" />
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mb-6 flex space-x-2">
              <Tabs
                defaultValue={"swedish"}
                value={language}
                onValueChange={handleLanguageChange}
                className="mx-1 w-full"
              >
                <TabsList>
                  <TabsTrigger value="swedish">Swedish</TabsTrigger>
                  <TabsTrigger value="english">English</TabsTrigger>
                </TabsList>
              </Tabs>
            </div>

            {Object.keys(rowSelection).length > 0 && (
              <div className="mb-4 flex space-x-2">
                <Button variant="outline" size="sm">
                //  onClick={handleEdit}
                 >
                  <Pencil className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Edit
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="outline"
                  size="sm"
                  className="text-red-500 hover:text-red-700"
                >
                  <Trash2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" /> Delete
                </Button>
              </div>
            )}

            <div className="rounded-md border">
              <Table>
                <TableHeader>
                  {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
                    <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                      {headerGroup.headers.map((header) =>
                        <TableHead key={header.id}>
                          {header.isPlaceholder
                            ? null
                            : flexRender(
                                header.column.columnDef.header,
                                header.getContext(),
                              )}
                        </TableHead>
                      ))}
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody>
                  {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
                    table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                      <TableRow
                        key={row.id}
                        Data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                        onClick={() => handleRowClick(row.original)}
                      >
                        {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                          <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                            {flexRender(
                              cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                              cell.getContext(),
                            )}
                          </TableCell>
                        ))}
                      </TableRow>
                    ))
                  ) : (
                    <TableRow>
                      <TableCell
                        colSpan={columns.length}
                        className="h-24 text-center"
                      >
No results.
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  )}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-center justify-between space-x-2 py-4">
              <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
                {/* {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
                {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected. */}
              </div>
              <div className="space-x-2">
                <Button
                  variant="outline"
                  size="sm"
                  // onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
                  // disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
                >
                  Previous
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="outline"
                  size="sm"
                  // onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
                  // disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
                >
                  Next
                </Button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        { (isDrawerOpen && selectedModule) &&  
        <QuestionDrawer
            isOpen={isDrawerOpen}
            onClose={() => setIsDrawerOpen(false)}
            question={selectedModule}
          />
        }
        </div>
       )} 
      { createModule &&
        // <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <CreateModuleCard
            open={createModule}
            setOpen={setCreateModule}
            levelId={params.levelId}
          />
        // </Suspense>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

here is creating components
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "~/components/ui/button";
import { Input } from "~/components/ui/input";
import { Label } from "~/components/ui/label";
import { Switch } from "~/components/ui/switch";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "~/components/ui/select";
import { Dialog, DialogContent, DialogFooter } from "~/components/ui/dialog";
import Image from "next/image";
import { api } from "~/trpc/react";
import Tiptap from "~/components/global/tiptap";
import { ScrollArea } from "~/components/ui/scroll-area";

export default function CreateModuleCard({
  open,
  setOpen,
  levelId,
}: {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: (open: boolean) => void;
  levelId: string;
}) {
  const [newItemData, setNewItemData] = useState<Record<string, any>>({});
  const [options, setOptions] = useState<{ text: string; isCorrect: boolean }[]>(
    [],
  );
  const [newOption, setNewOption] = useState<string>("");
  const {
    data: languages,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = api.global.fetchAllLanguages.useQuery();
  const createLevelQuestion = api.content.createLevelQuestion.useMutation();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (open && module) {
  //     console.log("Module:", module);
  //     setNewItemData(module);
  //   }
  // }, [open, module]);

  const handleAddOption = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (newOption.trim() !== "") {
      setOptions([...options, { text: newOption, isCorrect: false }]);
      setNewOption("");
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteOption = (index: number) => {
    setOptions(options.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const handleCorrectToggle = (index: number) => {
    setOptions((prevOptions) =>
      prevOptions.map((option, i) =>
        i === index ? { ...option, isCorrect: !option.isCorrect } : option,
      ),
    );
  };

  const handleInputChange = (
    key: string,
    value: string | File | null | boolean | string[],
  ) => {
    console.log(newItemData, "newItemData");
    setNewItemData((prev) => ({ ...prev, [key]: value }));
  };

  const onUpdate = async () => {
    
    console.log(newItemData);
    await createLevelQuestion.mutateAsync({
      levelId: levelId,
      languageId: newItemData.language,
      explanation: newItemData.content,
      question: newItemData.question,
      options: options,
      isHidden: newItemData.isHidden,
    });
    setOpen(false);
  };

  if (isError) return <div>Error</div>;

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen} modal={false}>
      <DialogContent className="flex flex-col sm:max-w-[500px] max-h-[700px]" >
        <ScrollArea className="flex-grow overflow-auto">
          <form className="space-y-4">
            <div className="flex space-x-4">
              <div className="flex-1">
                <Label htmlFor="thumbnail">Thumbnail</Label>
                <div className="mt-1 flex items-center">
                  {newItemData.thumbnail && (
                    <Image
                      width={32}
                      height={32}
                      src={newItemData.thumbnail!}
                      alt="Thumbnail"
                      className="mr-4 h-16 w-16 rounded"
                    />
                  )}
                  <Label
                    htmlFor="file-upload"
                    className="cursor-pointer rounded-md bg-white font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-500"
                  >
                    <span>Upload a file</span>
                    <Input
                      id="file-upload"
                      name="file-upload"
                      type="file"
                      className="sr-only"
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        handleInputChange(
                          "thumbnail",
                          e.target.files?.item.name![0],
                        )
                      }
                    />
                  </Label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* Dynamic Titles, Slug, and Language */}
            <div className="flex-1">
              <Label htmlFor="slug">Slug</Label>
              <Input
                id="slug"
                value={newItemData.slug}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange("slug", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1">
              <Label htmlFor="language">Language</Label>
              {isLoading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
              ) : (
                <Select
                  value={newItemData.language?.id} // Change to id
                  onValueChange={(value) =>
                    handleInputChange("language", value)
                  } // value will be the id now
                >
                  <SelectTrigger className="w-full">
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a Language" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                  <SelectContent>
                    {languages!.map((lang) => (
                      <SelectItem key={lang.id} value={lang.id}>
                        {" "}
                        {/* Store id instead of name */}
                        {lang.name!}
                      </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1">
              <Label htmlFor="language">Question</Label>
              <Tiptap
                className="mt-3 h-[100px]"
                message={""}
                handleMessageChange={(message) =>
                  handleInputChange("question", message)
                }
                isLoadingMessage={false}
                hotReload={false}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="flex-1">
              <div className="mt-4">
                <Label htmlFor="options">Options</Label>
                <div className="mt-2 flex space-x-2">
                  <Input
                    value={newOption}
                    onChange={(e) => setNewOption(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Add new option"
                  />
                  <Button type="button" onClick={handleAddOption}>
                    Add Option
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <ul className="mt-4 space-y-2">
                  {options.map((option, index) => (
                    <li key={index} className="flex items-center space-x-2">
                      <Input
                        value={option.text}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          setOptions((prevOptions) =>
                            prevOptions.map((opt, i) =>
                              i == index
                                ? { ...opt, text: e.target.value }
                                : opt,
                            ),
                          )
                        }
                      />
                      <label class="flex items-center">
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          checked={option.isCorrect}
                          onChange={() => handleCorrectToggle(index)}
                        />
                        <span className="ml-2">Correct</span>
                      </label>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        size="sm"
                        onClick={() => handleDeleteOption(index)}
                      >
                        Delete
                      </Button>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <Label htmlFor="language">Answer Description</Label>
              <Tiptap
                className="mt-3 h-[250px]"
                message={""}
                handleMessageChange={(message) =>
                  handleInputChange("content", message)
                }
                isLoadingMessage={false}
                hotReload={false}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Additional form inputs */}
            <div className="mt-4 flex items-center space-x-2">
              <Switch
                id="is-hidden"
                defaultChecked={false}
                checked={newItemData.isHidden}
                onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                  handleInputChange("isHidden", checked);
                }}
              />
              <Label htmlFor="is-hidden">Is Hidden</Label>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-4 flex items-center space-x-2">
              <Switch
                id="is-practice"
                defaultChecked={false}
                checked={newItemData.isPractice}
                onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                  handleInputChange("isPractice", checked);
                }}
              />
              <Label htmlFor="is-practice">Is Practice</Label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </ScrollArea>
        <DialogFooter>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={()=>{onUpdate()}}>
            Update
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outline" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}


